# Multiply a 1D tensor with a 4D tensor in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to make a calculation between 2 tensors: 1D tensor `[batch_size, value]` and 4D tensor `[batch_size, L, W, D]`.

The calculation I would like to perform can be expressed in the following for-loop:

```py
tensor1D = ... #shape = [batch_size, value]
tensor4D = ... #shape = [batch_size, L, W, D]
result = tensor4D

for i in range(batch_size):
    result[i] = tensor1D[i] * tensor4D[i]

return result
```

the `result` is what I would like to calculate

Answer (score 0):

You can first change the shape of `tensor1D` to the shape of `tensor4D` by using `broadcast_to` method, and then multiply it.

Try this:

```
batch_szie, l_size, w_size, d_size = 10, 2, 3, 4 # for example
tensor1D = tf.random.uniform((batch_szie,1))                    # shape = (10,1)
# the last dimension is 1, if it's not, uncomment below line
# tensor1D = tf.expand_dims(tensor1D, axis=-1)
tensor4D = tf.random.uniform((batch_szie,l_size,w_size,d_size)) # shape = (10,2,3,4)

# reshape tensor1D to the shape of tensor4D
tensor1D_converted = tf.reshape(
    tf.broadcast_to(tensor1D, [tensor4D.shape[0], tensor4D.shape[1]*tensor4D.shape[2]* tensor4D.shape[3]]), 
     tf.shape(tensor4D))

result = tf.multiply(tensor4D,tensor1D_converted)
return result
```